# Why does this else statement runs anyway?

Tags: c#

so basically, I ran into a problem, I can't figure out.
I have this code:

```
if ((v - e.Delta) <= 0) vScrollBar1.Value = vScrollBar1.Minimum;
if ((v - e.Delta) >= vScrollBar1.Maximum) vScrollBar1.Value = vScrollBar1.Maximum;
else vScrollBar1.Value -= e.Delta;
```

Even though the first if statement is true and runs its code, it runs the "else" code anyway.
Example: v = 0, e.Delta = 120 so the first if statement is true and works, but I don't know why it runs the else statement anyway, it doesn't run when the second if statement is true.
Thank for answers/suggestions!

Comment: add an else before the second if

Comment: Both if statements are completely independent from each other. Your else only belongs to the latter.

Comment: Thanks men! You both helped a lot! *.*

Comment: I will guess that this part will never be true...    ((v - e.Delta) >= vScrollBar1.Maximum)     (But I would have put the same code in myself just in case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two `if`s are independent.

```
if ((v - e.Delta) <= 0) vScrollBar1.Value = vScrollBar1.Minimum;

if ((v - e.Delta) >= vScrollBar1.Maximum) vScrollBar1.Value = vScrollBar1.Maximum;
else vScrollBar1.Value -= e.Delta;
```

You should add an `else` before your second `if`. Like this:

```
if      ((v - e.Delta) <= 0)                   vScrollBar1.Value = vScrollBar1.Minimum;
else if ((v - e.Delta) >= vScrollBar1.Maximum) vScrollBar1.Value = vScrollBar1.Maximum;
else                                           vScrollBar1.Value -= e.Delta;
```

Comment: I was just about to add an answer like this, ppl who commented, practically said the answer. :) But thanks for answering! :)

Answer (score 0):

You were missing initial `else` in second line,
but even better is to use ternary operator for this:

```
 vScrollBar1.Value = 
     v - e.Delta <= 0?                   vScrollBar1.Minimum:
     v - e.Delta >= vScrollBar1.Maximum? vScrollBar1.Maximum:
                                         vScrollBar1.Value - e.Delta;
```

Comment: Using the ternary operator here is equivalent to using `if else-if else` - I personally think nested ternary operators are less clear than `if else-if else`, but it's an opinion one way or another.

Comment: I use `if else if else` when code in each block is performing a different function. When all options are equivalent, as here, (they all assign a value to the same target variable) then I think ternary operator more clearly expresses the functional purpose of the code. (There is only one thing going on... and representing it as one statement is closely to the functional intent than representing it as multiple statements hidden in `if else if else ` block)

Comment: I think a lot of it has to do with formatting the branches - the formatting here is really clear, but I haven't seen it used often (maybe ever?), but in retrospect I agree here and will probably adopt this style myself.

Comment: @Preston, Yes, I agree with you. The formatting can easily destroy the readability/clarity, and the formatting I use with multiple ternary branches in scenarios like this is not common usage.   I really wish Resharper had this as an option for its auto-formatting of ternarys, but alas....

Answer (score 0):

Both `if`s are different. You see, the order for conditionals in C# is `if-else if-else`. So, make that second `if` an `else if` and your logic should function as expected.

```
if ((v - e.Delta) <= 0) vScrollBar1.Value = vScrollBar1.Minimum;
else if ((v - e.Delta) >= vScrollBar1.Maximum) vScrollBar1.Value = vScrollBar1.Maximum;
else vScrollBar1.Value -= e.Delta;
```

*De rien!*